# how do I SET the GOPATH environment variable in go 1.11 on Ubuntu? What file must I edit?

Tags: go

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~/.work/src/github.hpe.com/hybridpoc/marketplace-terraform-tf-broker$ go run main.go
main.go:10:2: cannot find package "github.hpe.com/hybridpoc/marketplace-terraform-tf-broker/broker/github" in any of:
        /home/ubuntu/go/src/github.hpe.com/hybridpoc/marketplace-terraform-tf-broker/broker/github (from $GOROOT)
        /home/ubuntu/work/src/github.hpe.com/hybridpoc/marketplace-terraform-tf-broker/broker/github (from $GOPATH)
main.go:11:2: cannot find package "github.hpe.com/hybridpoc/marketplace-terraform-tf-broker/handlers" in any of:
        /home/ubuntu/go/src/github.hpe.com/hybridpoc/marketplace-terraform-tf-broker/handlers (from $GOROOT)
        /home/ubuntu/work/src/github.hpe.com/hybridpoc/marketplace-terraform-tf-broker/handlers (from $GOPATH)
```

Comment: If you are using bash as your shell then `~/.bashrc` would be a good place. Alternatively you can set it on the command line (`export GOPATH=...`), but that setting would be gone after the next login.

Comment: It seems that the paths are already set, but you could be working in the wrong directory. Go is looking in ~/work whereas you're working in ~/.work (notice the "dot")

Answer (score 0):

This question seems to be about setting environment variables, not about the Go programming language.

As such, there are many answers. For example [this ask.ubuntu question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/58814/how-do-i-add-environment-variables).

The easiest way for experimentation is prefixing your commands with `NAME=value`, for example:

```
$ GOPATH=/some/path go <command>
```

Or, if you want to extend it to multiple shell commands within the same session, do:

```
$ export GOPATH=/some/path
$ go <command>
```

Once these work well, add the `GOPATH` setting to your `~/.bashrc` file so that future sessions will find it without needing to `export`